# Is there a way to import the old Aptana HTML editor in Aptana 3?

Tags: plugins, aptana, html-editor, aptana3

I was used to the old Aptana HTML editor in Aptana 2, and I liked the quick preview feature (tabs at the bottom).

Now I know that this may come as me having separation anxiety, but I feel that it was a good productivity feature.

Now I already tried copying it over from the plugins directory from aptana 2 into the plugins directory in Aptana 3, restarting Aptana, and checking in the internal editors list under file associations, but I can't seem to find it.

Also I realize that just using Aptana 2 and ignoring Aptana 3 might be a possible solution, but Aptana 3 also has very good features that I thoroughly enjoy.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. The architectures are completely different, and you would have to copy a much larger chunk than just that one plugin for it to even conceivably work.

I would instead suggesting what it is that was useful or important about the previous feature, and filing a feature request against Aptana Studio 3.

Comment: Now where should I go for suggesting this functionality? I saw that there was some an https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/ website to which some people were submitting requests, but this project is not public.

Comment: Please go to jira.appcelerator.org, and use the Aptana project.